# Firebase - Android: Retrieve ArrayList from Firebase - Failed to bounce type

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am facing the following issue:

I upload an object to my firebase and one of the attributes is a ArrayList.
This works like a charm and I get all the objects with their attributes into my firebase.

When I want to retrieve this data I get following error:

```
com.firebase.client.FirebaseException: Failed to bounce to type
```

This happens, because I cannot retrieve the data from the Firebase as an ArrayList and import it in an the same type of object I used to upload.
[image]
How can I consume these type of firebase objects into a java object?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase database. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: You also have shown no code of what you've tried. The Firebase documentation on [saving data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/saving-data.html) and [retrieving data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html) should give you a good handle to get started.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to find a solution.
"Groupmember" is an Arraylist, but it does contain HashMap instead of the Object I passed for upload - makes sense! :-)